# External display resolution - cursor gets lost

Tags: display, resolution

I connected my new K272HUL display to my Macbook Pro Retina 15". The issue is that the resolution that the monitor displays seems to be too large (2560x1440) and my mouse gets lost in the display. My menu bar is completely hidden and I can only see a little bit of it if I hover over it.

Any clue on how I could fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force RGB mode on MacBook. Here is how: http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor